# Is the title הזקנה only used in reference to an old woman? Or out of respect?

Tags: words, hebrew, age, cemetery-grave, gravestone-inscription

I am asking this question in reference to placing a title on a tombstone for a special lady (unfortunately did not live long, 40s):

What title is most appropriate or respectful?

Is the title הזקנה only used in reference to an old woman?

Or could be placed as a token of respect?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This is not the first question I've seen you ask about tombstone inscriptions in recent history. If you've lost someone, you have my sincere condolences. || Please don't rely on anything you hear here in practice. We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info; please ask a competent halachic authority if you need to know practical answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is relevant to the laws of gravestone inscriptions, but the mishna in [Avos (5:25)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%90) says

> בן ששים לזקנה
>
> 60 years to "old age" (זקנה)

I think it makes sense to reserve the designation of זקן\זקנה to people aged 60 and above, but [one should consult a rabbi for practical advice](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).